# Is it allowed to edit question/answer only to simplify the example?

Tags: discussion, edits

Sometimes I find questions/answers where the title is very good, but the discussed example in the question/answer seems over complicated to me.

For example, in [JS Regex, how to replace the captured groups only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only) the question is very clear, but the discussed example is `name="some_text_0_some_text"` and the regex to the answer is `str.replace(/(.*value="\w+)(\d+)(\w+".*)/, "$1!NEW_ID!$3")` (which is wrong now, but was correct before the question has been edited `value` to `name`..).

Would it be acceptable to just edit the question example from `name="some_text_0_some_text"` to `abc0efg` and the solution to `str.replace(/(\w+)\d+(\w+)/, "$1!NEW_ID!$2")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a frequently-linked question includes certain implementation details only relevant for OP's original situation, but which are *definitely* not at all relevant to the core of the question nor any potential answers, I think removing them would make the question and answers more easily understandable for everyone else. IMO, it would be beneficial for the same reason that boiling code down to MVEs is useful. That said, the rule is that changes to posts must preserve the intent of the author, so make sure the asker is OK with it first (and if changes are made, make sure that all the answers are tweaked to line up with the simplified question).

Ideally, the library of programming questions and answers that is Stack Overflow should be most useful for *future readers*, and the most easily digestible Q/As are trimmed down to the base problem, without anything extraneous. But make *absolutely certain* to only consider removing what is surely irrelevant to visitors and potential answerers. If you aren't 100% sure, or if you aren't a domain expert (or if OP disagrees), better to leave it alone.

If the question had been about nearly anything other than Javascript, I think your suggestion would have likely been an oversimplification because it would have permitted *completely new* solutions that might have distracted from what used to be the main issue of the question.

---

Specifically, a match would be possible using **fixed-width lookbehind** for a word character, without using any groups at all, eg

```js
console.log(
  'abc0efg'.replace(
    /(?<=\w)\d(?=\w)/,
    '!NEW_ID!'
  )
);
```

In contrast, in the original version of the question, the part of the match that comes before the digits does *not* have a fixed-width, which would require the use of a capturing group in nearly any other language (most regex engines do not support variable-length lookbehind). So, if this were anything other than Javascript, your suggested edit to the question *might* change it too much, because it would make the initial capture group unnecessary, and given the question title, people who visit the question are likely thinking about situations that seem to require capture groups...

But Javascript just so happens to be one of the [very few languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Part_2) that supports **variable-length lookbehind**, so the use of groups is *already* [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954927/js-regex-how-to-replace-the-captured-groups-only#answer-57450029).

---

Was that something you considered? That's just an example to illustrate that you have to be *very* careful not to accidentally fundamentally change the situation. Since highly-voted, often-linked QAs are probably the greatest gems we have on the site, don't be afraid to ask for input from experts in chat and on Meta first before making alterations, just to make sure, even if OP is already OK with it.

Comment: How do I contact the OP? I believe when I click on "edit question" and save it, then its just saved without the permission of OP?

Comment: You can comment under their post and they'll get an inbox notification (hopefully they'll respond... SO has lots of users who don't participate anymore). Right, if you just edit and save, it'll save immediately, though they'll be notified of the change.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I agree with Yvette. This is changing the user's intent. If you feel the site requires a clearer question for the topic you can post one - and answer it.

And then there is the possibility that the older question can be voted to close as a Duplicate of yours if your is really better...

Comment: Would you recommend to create the new QA as community wiki?

Comment: @Adam That totally depends on the circumstances. Others reading the question and feeling they have something more to contribute than what's in your answer have the option of writing their own answer. At that point, you could contact them in comments and propose combining the information into one (community) answer. However, if the approach is different from that in your answer I'd consider leaving the two separate - that makes it easier for others to follow than one very long answer. Or, if you bring up the topic in chat and others find it useful, together you could start a comm-wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against editing code within questions, as usually the code is a part of the problem statement.

The other issue is - it's an old question. Edited posts are bumped to the front page, so it's something to be mindful of. How pertinent or useful is the edit and does it warrant bumping an old post to the front page.

Rather than editing someone else's code, I'd recommend posting a new answer. Editing code comes into that issue of grey areas where there's a lot of sensitivity about removing the original intent of the author.

So if in doubt, don't.

Comment: I know the question is old, but when you search for regex groups, this is top 1 result in Google. I wanted to correct the answer at least that its correct to the current question, so it will be bumped anyway. (Btw I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Adam I'm not worried about the downvote - what is wrong with writing an answer? I wrote this on a post with a heap of answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721904/make-body-fill-entire-screen/30428430#30428430 as none of them answered my question at the time. due to changing code

Comment: I would like to change the question to make the presented example a lot simpler. Giving an answer to the overcomplicated example is not my aim.

Comment: @Adam I don't think you  should change the question.

Comment: Ok this is a test comment for retracting flags...